# Good SEO information (NO MARKETING)

Tags: seo

Where can I find information on SEO without all the marketing crap? Googling always results in "learn SEO fast!" or "buy our SEO training program" I can never find something that is "free". I know much already but because I see no "organization" in SEO I cannot verify if what I know is everything (in IT that is almost never the case but you can get close); so is there at least a good book for SEO or something rather than marketers opinions?

I'd like official information from Google, Yahoo/Bing or a reputable book. But no website that is trying to sell me something (unless it's reputable for having information that I do *not* have to buy). *SEO is not a trade secret is what I am trying to say...*

Comment: "I'd like official information from Google, [...] SEO is not a trade secret." Actually, yes it is. What to rank highest is *their* problem to solve, not yours to manufacture. Which is why there *is* no "official information" beyond vague hints, mostly about what's bad rather than good. If they told everyone how to rank highly, enough people would do it as to even them all out and make it pointless. Then they'd have to change the rules again, starting a cycle that should already be sounding familiar.

Comment: I maintain some guidelines and tutorials here: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/seo-guidelines-and-checklists.html

Answer (score 1):

Start by http://www.seomoz.org/. It is a really nice resource.

[Google guide for webmasters](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf&rct=j&q=google%20seo%20guide&ei=apSTTq6CBYGltwf199n0Bg&usg=AFQjCNEMj8KHxhxQz9cMLoMxMDiLdrAbJw&cad=rja) and [yahoo! seo styleguide](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://styleguide.yahoo.com/resources/optimize-search-engines/seo-basics&rct=j&q=yahoo%20seo%20guide&ei=hZSTTv3lCoa2twfQpsj7Bg&usg=AFQjCNH3u7RgAP7Idn2x8azZxBJG62CZAA&cad=rja) are also very useful.

Good readings.

Comment: No problem dude, go ahead. I think still there are a few fellas who can greatly contribute with your question. Choose wisely, read everything.

Answer (score 1):

I read this two books and I think you can extract some good informations if you are an average user and a lot of good suggestions if you are a beginner. The books are:

- [The Art of SEO: Mastering Search Engine Optimization (Theory in Practice)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596518862)
- [Seo Warrior](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/059615707X)

Finally, as Dave said, [Seomoz.org](http://www.seomoz.org) is great as well.