# SEO tutorials and other learning materials

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

Please recommend one or two trustworthy SEO tutorials or any other reliable source of SEO wisdom. :)
I watched the video tutorial from lynda.com and I liked it a lot, but I don't know how up to date it is.
I am also reading SEObook by Aaron Wall. 
Do you think this is a good source?

Thank you!

Comment: Same as http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20830/good-seo-information-no-marketing/20833

Comment: Thank you!
It's not exactly the same though - for example, they don't mention lynda.com tutorial and Aaron Wall's SEOBook.

Comment: The question is the same. Of course every person wil give you the informations that he thinks are the best.